# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to update Gridview by Code behind file.
on clicking the update button i get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword set
The tableName is showing properly

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Label l=GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ID") as Label;
    TextBox question=GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("questions") as TextBox;
    TextBox answer=GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("answer") as TextBox;
    TextBox option1=GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("op1") as TextBox;
    TextBox option2=GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("op2") as TextBox;
    TextBox option3=GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("op3") as TextBox;
    TextBox option4=GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("op4") as TextBox;
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "update " + tableName + " set [questions]='" + question.Text + "',[answer]='" + answer.Text + "',[op1]='" + option1.Text + "',[op2]='" + option2.Text+"',[op3]='"+option3.Text+"',[op4]='"+option4.Text+"' where ID="+l.Text;
    //GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I have initialized `tableName` variable inside Page_Load event handler

```
 if (!IsPostBack)   
 {
 ch_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ch_id"].ToString());
 c_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["course_id"]);
  if (c_id == 1)
  { 
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["query"].DefaultValue = "select * from J2EE_testMaster where chapter_id=" + ch_id; 
    tableName = "J2EE_testMaster";
  } 
 }
```

Comment: First thing to fix: don't embed values in SQL like this. Use parameterized SQL instead. Fix that (and set the parameters accordingly) - it'll then be a lot easier to look at the SQL and work out any remaining problems, if there are any.

Comment: what is your variable `tableName` value.?

Comment: actually i used this because my tablename will be dynamic

Comment: @Sudhakar : its Android_testMaster

Comment: where do you declare `tableName` variable?

Comment: Using a "dynamic" tablename is asking for trouble. And so is using TextBox.Text in a query.

Comment: @ekad : yes i did, i even tested its value with a alert box

Comment: Can you add the code where you declare `tableName` variable?

Comment: Yes i declared it in Page Load if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ch_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ch_id"].ToString());
                c_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["course_id"]);
                if (c_id == 1)
                {
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["query"].DefaultValue = "select * from J2EE_testMaster where chapter_id=" + ch_id;
                    tableName = "J2EE_testMaster";
                }

Comment: so its like from the course id table is decided

Comment: Move the code in your comment inside the question. Here is unreadable. Look for the EDIT link under your question text

Comment: What happen to the variable tableName if the c_id is not 1?

Comment: @Steve i am just testing and the c_id is 1 or 2 or 3 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, here's what your `Page_Load` method look like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    { 
        ch_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ch_id"].ToString()); 
        c_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["course_id"]); 
        if (c_id == 1) 
        { 
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["query"].DefaultValue = "select * from J2EE_testMaster where chapter_id=" + ch_id; 
            tableName = "J2EE_testMaster"; 
        }
    }
}
```

That will make `tableName` empty when `GridView1_RowUpdating` is executed, so the value of `SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand` will become `update  set [questions]=...` instead of `update J2EE_testMaster set [questions]=...`. You need to set the `tableName` value outside of `if (!IsPostBack)` block:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["course_id"]); 
    if (c_id == 1) 
    { 
        tableName = "J2EE_testMaster"; 
    }

    if (!IsPostBack) 
    { 
        ch_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ch_id"].ToString()); 
        if (c_id == 1) 
        { 
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["query"].DefaultValue = "select * from J2EE_testMaster where chapter_id=" + ch_id; 
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to parameterize your SQL query to avoid [SQL Injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).